# flutter not inserting in the database while

Tags: flutter, dart

when trying to insert a new invoice into the database, i put a print statement to check if it is working properly, the print statement works, but the value i gave in the form are not inserted in the database, while i put the data in the proper way, i tried to manipulat the form but it did not help at all. i was able to insert in the database but when i made a hot refresh nothing works at, i do not know what cause this problem, even when trying to insert data from an api in that table i got the same problem.

i want to insert data given by the user in the invoice table, or insert data coming from the APi in the database.

```
class Invoices {
  late int? iInvoiceId;
  final String? iCustomerId;
  final DateTime iInvoiceDate;
  late String? iSerialCode;
  late int? iSerialSequenceNo;
  late String iUsername;
  final String iInvoiceType;
  final String iInvoiceStatus;
  final String iCurrencyType;
  final double iTotalGrossAmountNoVat;
  final double iTotalDiscountNoVat;
  final double iTotalAmountNoVat;
  final double iTotalAmountWithVat;
  final int iServerId1;
  final int iServerId2;
  final DateTime iCreateDate;
  final DateTime iLastTargetUpdate;
  final DateTime iLastSourceUpdate;
  late String s_code;

  Invoices({
    this.iInvoiceId,
    required this.iCustomerId,
    required this.iInvoiceDate,
    this.iSerialCode,
    this.iSerialSequenceNo,
    required this.iUsername,
    required this.iInvoiceType,
    required this.iInvoiceStatus,
    required this.iCurrencyType,
    required this.iTotalGrossAmountNoVat,
    required this.iTotalDiscountNoVat,
    required this.iTotalAmountNoVat,
    required this.iTotalAmountWithVat,
    required this.iServerId1,
    required this.iServerId2,
    required this.iCreateDate,
    required this.iLastTargetUpdate,
    required this.iLastSourceUpdate,
    required this.s_code,
  });

  factory Invoices.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Invoices(
      iCustomerId: map['i_customer_id'],
      iInvoiceDate: DateTime.parse(map['i_invoice_date']),
      iSerialCode: map['i_serialcode'],
      iSerialSequenceNo: map['i_serialsequenceno'],
      iUsername: map['i_username'],
      iInvoiceType: map['i_invoicetype'],
      iInvoiceStatus: map['i_invoicestatus'],
      iCurrencyType: map['i_currency_type'],
      iTotalGrossAmountNoVat:
          double.tryParse(map['i_totalgrossamount_novat'].toString()) ?? 0.0,
      iTotalDiscountNoVat:
          double.tryParse(map['i_totaldiscount_novat'].toString()) ?? 0.0,
      iTotalAmountNoVat:
          double.tryParse(map['i_totalamount_novat'].toString()) ?? 0.0,
      iTotalAmountWithVat:
          double.tryParse(map['i_totalamountwithvat'].toString()) ?? 0.0,
      iServerId1: map['i_server_id1'],
      iServerId2: map['i_server_id2'],
      iCreateDate: DateTime.parse(map['i_create_date']),
      iLastTargetUpdate: DateTime.parse(map['i_last_target_update']),
      iLastSourceUpdate: DateTime.parse(map['i_last_source_update']),
      s_code: map['s_code'],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'i_customer_id': iCustomerId,
      'i_invoice_date': iInvoiceDate.toIso8601String(),
      'i_serialcode': iSerialCode,
      'i_serialsequenceno': iSerialSequenceNo,
      'i_username': iUsername,
      'i_invoicetype': iInvoiceType,
      'i_invoicestatus': iInvoiceStatus,
      'i_currency_type': iCurrencyType,
      'i_totalgrossamount_novat': iTotalGrossAmountNoVat,
      'i_totaldiscount_novat': iTotalDiscountNoVat,
      'i_totalamount_novat': iTotalAmountNoVat,
      'i_totalamountwithvat': iTotalAmountWithVat,
      'i_server_id1': iServerId1,
      'i_server_id2': iServerId2,
      'i_create_date': iCreateDate.toIso8601String(),
      'i_last_target_update': iLastTargetUpdate.toIso8601String(),
      'i_last_source_update': iLastSourceUpdate.toIso8601String(),
      's_code': s_code,
    };
  }

  Invoices copyWith({
    String? iCustomerId,
    DateTime? iInvoiceDate,
    String? iSerialCode,
    int? iSerialSequenceNo,
    String? iUsername,
    String? iInvoiceType,
    String? iInvoiceStatus,
    String? iCurrencyType,
    double? iTotalGrossAmountNoVat,
    double? iTotalDiscountNoVat,
    double? iTotalAmountNoVat,
    double? iTotalAmountWithVat,
    int? iServerId1,
    int? iServerId2,
    DateTime? iCreateDate,
    DateTime? iLastTargetUpdate,
    DateTime? iLastSourceUpdate,
    String? s_code,
  }) {
    return Invoices(
      iCustomerId: iCustomerId ?? this.iCustomerId,
      iInvoiceDate: iInvoiceDate ?? this.iInvoiceDate,
      iSerialCode: iSerialCode ?? this.iSerialCode,
      iSerialSequenceNo: iSerialSequenceNo ?? this.iSerialSequenceNo,
      iUsername: iUsername ?? this.iUsername,
      iInvoiceType: iInvoiceType ?? this.iInvoiceType,
      iInvoiceStatus: iInvoiceStatus ?? this.iInvoiceStatus,
      iCurrencyType: iCurrencyType ?? this.iCurrencyType,
      iTotalGrossAmountNoVat:
          iTotalGrossAmountNoVat ?? this.iTotalGrossAmountNoVat,
      iTotalDiscountNoVat: iTotalDiscountNoVat ?? this.iTotalDiscountNoVat,
      iTotalAmountNoVat: iTotalAmountNoVat ?? this.iTotalAmountNoVat,
      iTotalAmountWithVat: iTotalAmountWithVat ?? this.iTotalAmountWithVat,
      iServerId1: iServerId1 ?? this.iServerId1,
      iServerId2: iServerId2 ?? this.iServerId2,
      iCreateDate: iCreateDate ?? this.iCreateDate,
      iLastTargetUpdate: iLastTargetUpdate ?? this.iLastTargetUpdate,
      iLastSourceUpdate: iLastSourceUpdate ?? this.iLastSourceUpdate,
      s_code: s_code ?? this.s_code,
    );
  }
}
```

here is my class for creating database and table

```
Future<Database> customerDataBase() async {
  return openDatabase(
    join(await getDatabasesPath(), "invoice.db"),
    onCreate: (db, version) async { await db.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stock(
          s_stock_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
          s_name TEXT,
          s_code TEXT,
          s_short_name TEXT,
          s_main_group_name TEXT,
          s_sub_group_name TEXT,
          s_description TEXT,
          s_quantity INTEGER,
          s_server_id1 INTEGER,
          s_server_id2 INTEGER,
          s_create_date TEXT,
          s_last_update TEXT
        )
      ''');await db.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS invoices(
      i_invoice_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
      i_customer_id TEXT,
      i_invoice_date TEXT,
      i_serialcode TEXT,
      i_serialsequenceno INTEGER,
      i_username TEXT,
      i_invoicetype TEXT,
      i_invoicestatus TEXT,
      i_currency_type TEXT,
      i_totalgrossamount_novat REAL,
      i_totaldiscount_novat REAL,
      i_totalamount_novat REAL,
      i_totalamountwithvat REAL,
      i_server_id1 INTEGER,
      i_server_id2 INTEGER,
      i_create_date TEXT,
      i_last_target_update TEXT,
      i_last_source_update TEXT,
      s_code TEXT,
      FOREIGN KEY (i_customer_id) REFERENCES customers (c_code)
    )
  '''); },
    version: 1,
  );
}
Future<void> insertInvoice(Invoices invoices) async {
  final Database db = await customerDataBase();
  await db.insert(
      'invoices', invoices.toMap());
}
```

here is the class for the form

```
class addInvoice extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _addInvoiceState createState() => _addInvoiceState();
}

class _addInvoiceState extends State<addInvoice> {
  List<int> _customerIds = []; // List to store the customer IDs
  String? _selectedCustomerId;
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> _customerIdsAndNames = [];
  int _currentPageIndex = 0;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Fetch the list of customers when the widget initializes
    _fetchCustomers();
  }

  void _fetchCustomers() async {
    try {
      List<Map<String, dynamic>> customerIdsAndNames =
          await fetchCustomerIdsAndNamesFromDatabase();
      setState(() {
        _customerIdsAndNames = customerIdsAndNames;
      });
    } catch (error) {
      print('Error fetching customer IDs and names: $error');
    }
  }

  final TextEditingController _iInvoiceDateController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _iUsernameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _invoiceTypeController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _invoiceStatusController =
      TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _currencyTypeController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _totalGrossAmountNoVatController =
      TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _totalDiscountNoVatController =
      TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _totalAmountNoVatController =
      TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _totalAmountWithVatController =
      TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _iServerId1Controller = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _iServerId2Controller = TextEditingController();

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>(); // Add a GlobalKey

  bool _isSubmitting = false;
  String _statusMessage = '';

  // Function to generate unique invoice serial code
  static String generateRandomCode() {
    const length = 6; // Set the desired length of the random code
    const characters =
        'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';
    final random = Random();
    final code = List.generate(
        length, (_) => characters[random.nextInt(characters.length)]);
    return code.join();
  }

  void _submitFormAndSaveInvoiceItems() {
    // Call the submitForm method to save the invoice
    _submitForm();
    print("Invoice submitted");
    // Save invoice items (Add your logic here)
    // ...
  }

  void _submitForm() async {
    if (!_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      Navigator.pop(context, true);
    }

    if (!mounted) {
      return;
    }
    setState(() {
      _isSubmitting = true;
      _statusMessage = '';
    });
    final String? icustomer = _selectedCustomerId;
    final DateTime iInvoiceDate = DateTime.parse(_iInvoiceDateController.text);
    final String iUsername = _iUsernameController.text;
    final int iServerId1 = int.parse(_iServerId1Controller.text);
    final int iServerId2 = int.parse(_iServerId2Controller.text);
    final String s_code = generateRandomCode();

    final Invoices newInvoice = Invoices(
      iCustomerId: icustomer,
      iInvoiceDate: iInvoiceDate,
      iSerialCode: iUsername,
      iSerialSequenceNo: 0,
      iUsername: iUsername,
      iInvoiceType: _invoiceTypeController.text,
      iInvoiceStatus: _invoiceStatusController.text,
      iCurrencyType: _currencyTypeController.text,
      iTotalGrossAmountNoVat:
          double.parse(_totalGrossAmountNoVatController.text),
      iTotalDiscountNoVat: double.parse(_totalDiscountNoVatController.text),
      iTotalAmountNoVat: double.parse(_totalAmountNoVatController.text),
      iTotalAmountWithVat: double.parse(_totalAmountWithVatController.text),
      iServerId1: iServerId1,
      iServerId2: iServerId2,
      iCreateDate: DateTime.now(),
      iLastTargetUpdate: DateTime.now(),
      iLastSourceUpdate: DateTime.now(),
      s_code: s_code, // Assign the same serial code to the s_code property
    );

    try {
      await insertInvoice(newInvoice); // Insert into local database
      setState(() {
        _statusMessage = 'Invoice added successfully';
        _isSubmitting = false;
      });

      // Send a result back to the previous screen to trigger refresh
      Navigator.pop(context, true);
    } catch (error) {
      setState(() {
        _statusMessage = 'Failed to add invoice: $error';
        print(error);
        _isSubmitting = false;
      });
    }
  }

  void _onCustomerChanged(String? customerId) {
    // Change to int?
    setState(() {
      _selectedCustomerId = customerId;
    });
  }

  Future<void> _selectInvoiceDate() async {
    DateTime? pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
      firstDate: DateTime(2000),
      lastDate: DateTime(2101),
    );

    if (pickedDate != null && pickedDate != DateTime.now()) {
      setState(() {
        // Format the pickedDate to "YYYY-MM-DD" format
        String formattedDate =
            "${pickedDate.year}-${pickedDate.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${pickedDate.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}";
        _iInvoiceDateController.text = formattedDate;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Add Invoice"),
        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 28, 44, 58),
        actions: [
          // Save button to call _submitFormAndSaveInvoiceItems method
          IconButton(
            onPressed: _isSubmitting ? null : _submitFormAndSaveInvoiceItems,
            icon: Icon(Icons.save),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          // Place the IndexedStack at the bottom to maintain the form data
          Positioned.fill(
            child: IndexedStack(
              index: _currentPageIndex,
              children: [
                _buildInvoiceForm(),
           
              ],
            ),
          ),
          // Add other content here that should be displayed above the IndexedStack
        ],
      ),
      
    );
  }

  Widget _buildInvoiceForm() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Form(
        key: _formKey, // Assign the GlobalKey to the Form widget
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            DropdownSearch<Map<String, dynamic>>(
              items: _customerIdsAndNames,
              onChanged: (Map<String, dynamic>? selectedValue) {
                setState(() {
                  _selectedCustomerId = selectedValue?['c_code'];
                });
              },
              itemAsString: (Map<String, dynamic>? item) {
                return '${item?['c_code']} - ${item?['c_name']}';
              },
              selectedItem: _selectedCustomerId != null
                  ? _customerIdsAndNames.firstWhere(
                      (item) => item['c_code'] == _selectedCustomerId,
                    )
                  : null,
              validator: (Map<String, dynamic>? value) {
                if (value == null) {
                  return 'A customer is required';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: _selectInvoiceDate,
              child: AbsorbPointer(
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: _iInvoiceDateController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Invoice Date'),
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value!.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Invoice Date is required';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: _iUsernameController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Username'),
              validator: (value) {
                if (value!.isEmpty) {
                  return 'username is required';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: _invoiceTypeController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Invoice Type'),
              validator: (value) {
                if (value!.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Invoice Type is required';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: _invoiceStatusController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Invoice Status'),
              validator: (value) {
                if (value!.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Invoice Status is required';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: _currencyTypeController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Currency Type'),
              validator: (value) {
                if (value!.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Currency Type is required';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: _totalGrossAmountNoVatController,
              decoration:
                  InputDecoration(labelText: 'Total Gross Amount (No VAT)'),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              validator: (value) {
                if (value!.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Total Gross Amount is required';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: _totalDiscountNoVatController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Total Discount (No VAT)'),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              validator: (value) {
                if (value!.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Total Discount is required';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: _totalAmountNoVatController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Total Amount (No VAT)'),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              validator: (value) {
                if (value!.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Total Amount is required';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: _totalAmountWithVatController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Total Amount (With VAT)'),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              validator: (value) {
                if (value!.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Total Amount with VAT is required';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: _iServerId1Controller,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Server 1'),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              validator: (value) {
                if (value!.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Server 1 is required';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: _iServerId2Controller,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Server 2'),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              validator: (value) {
                if (value!.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Server 2 is required';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 16.0),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _isSubmitting ? null : _submitForm,
              child: const Text('Submit'),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
            Text(
              _statusMessage,
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
            ),
          ],
          // Rest of the form fields for adding an invoice...
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```